# Why is this if statement not functioning correctly

Tags: java, android, random, libgdx

```
public void chooseLane() {

    int lane = MathUtils.random(1, 3);
    System.out.println(lane);
    spawnCar();

}

public void spawnCar() {

    if(lane == 1){
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(carsb, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
        System.out.println("testing");

    }
```

in the `chooseLane()` it Prints out the int of lane (Set to random and print every second not shown) but when `lane == 1` it doesn't complete the spawnCar method. Any help please?

Comment: Use  `lane = MathUtils.random(1, 3);` in `chooseLane` method or pass  lane as parameter to `spawnCar` method

Answer (score 2):

declare the `lane` variable outside the `chooseLane()` method. Since, you are declaring the `lane` variable as local variable of `chooseLane()` that's why it can't be accessible outside the `chooseLane()` method.

```
int lane;

public void chooseLane() {

    lane = MathUtils.random(1, 3);
    System.out.println(lane);
    spawnCar();

}

public void spawnCar() {

    if(lane == 1){
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(carsb, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
        System.out.println("testing");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although now im running into a new problem, it seems like when it draws the sprite it only does though for what seems like a single frame, any idea on how I keep it from dissapearing instantly?

Comment: instantly its out of my guess.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have different instances of the variable `lane`

```
int lane = MathUtils.random(1, 3);
```

here `lane` is being redefined. Just remove `int` from that line.

Answer (score 1):

the `lane` you are setting in `chooseLane` and the one you are comparing inside `spawnCar` are not the same. You could add a parameter to spawnCar, avoiding to keep the `lane` class member

```
public void spawnCar(int lane) {

if(lane == 1){
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(carsb, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
    System.out.println("testing");

}
```